# How to migrate 'sub-collection' of fireStore to supabase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, supabase

I tried to migrate `fireStore` db to `supabase`.

The process for this is documented well in official documents:
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/resources/migrating-to-supabase/firestore-data

But when I run `node collections.js` to list all collections of fireStore, it shows all collections only.
fireStore has concept `subCollection` and I want to make it as separate Table in postgreSQL.

Even if that's not the case, I need to fetch data from sub-collection from fireStore.

Is it impossible now?

Comment: Have you tried giving the full path to the subcollection that you want to convert into a table?  You will almost certainly have to select a single subcollection nested under a single document.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you show me a simple example?

Comment: module.exports = (collectionName, doc, recordCounters, writeRecord) => {
  // modify the doc here
  return doc
}

-> From here, I can't access subcollection with path. If I write `doc.subcollectionName`, subcollectionName will point field of document, not subcollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [construct your `.js` file](module.exports = (collectionName, doc, recordCounters, writeRecord) => {
// modify the doc here
return doc
}), can you try to provide the sub-colleection path to `collectionName`, something like `myCollection/documentId/mySubcollection`

```js
module.exports = (collectionName, doc, recordCounters, writeRecord) => {
  // modify the doc here
  return doc
}
```